# Reaction rate derivation: amount of substance vs concentration

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

Let's say you have the reaction
$$A + B \; \rightarrow \; C.$$
I would like to understand why $\frac{\mathrm{d}[C]}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is proportional to $[A][B]$. I can see why
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}n_C}{\mathrm{d}t} \propto \frac{\text{number of collisions between } A \text{ and } B}{\text{time}} \propto [A][B],$$
but I cannot see why
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[C]}{\mathrm{d}t} \propto \frac{\text{number of collisions between } A \text{ and } B}{\text{time}}$$
because wouldn't this be invalid if the reaction changes the volume?

Comment: If the reaction mixture is in a dilute solution, you would not expect volume changes. If it is in the gas phase at constant pressure, that's a different story. So this assumes the volume is constant (and the reaction is homogeneous, i.e. in a single phase, typically a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the elementary reaction $\ce{A + B -> C}$, the following rate expression

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}C_A}{\mathrm{d}t} \propto C_A\;C_B$$

is only valid when:

1. The reaction is performed at constant volume with ideal mixing.
2. The rate follows a power-law model.
3. No inflows or outflows present (batch).

The fundamental equation from which this expression can be obtained is

$$\dot{n}_{Ao}-\dot{n}_{A}+r_AV=\frac{\mathrm{d}n_A}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Since no flows are present:

$\require{cancel}$

$$\cancel{\dot{n}_{Ao}}-\cancel{\dot{n}_{A}}+r_AV=\frac{\mathrm{d}n_A}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Considering constant volume:

$$n_A=C_A\;V\implies r_A\cancel{V}=\frac{\mathrm{d}(C_A\cancel{V})}{\mathrm{d}t}\implies -r_A=-\frac{\mathrm{d}C_A}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Considering a power law model:

$$-\frac{\mathrm{d}C_A}{\mathrm{d}t}\propto C_A\;C_B$$

Finally, using reaction stoichiometry to relate rates:

$$\frac{-r_A}{a}=\frac{r_C}{c}\implies r_C=-r_A\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}C_C}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}C_A}{\mathrm{d}t}\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}C_C}{\mathrm{d}t}\propto C_A\;C_B$$

Comment: Thank you! How exactly is $r_A$ defined?

Comment: @Silenus $-r_A$ is defined as the amount of limiting reagent A that is consumed per unit volume, per unit time. It usually has $\pu{\frac{mol}{dm^3\;s}}$ units, although constant volume allows for $\pu{\frac{M}{s}}$ units or equivalently, $\pu{\frac{mol}{L\;s}}$.

Comment: Note that the sign next to "r" indicates whether the species in question is being formed ($+r_A$) or consumed ($-r_A$).

Comment: A chemical engineer's approach!

Comment: We are not extinct yet :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}n_\mathrm{C}}{\mathrm{d}t} \propto R_\mathrm{AB} \propto [\ce{A}][\ce{B}]V$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}[\mathrm{C}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}n_\mathrm{C}}{V\mathrm{d}t} \propto \frac{R_\mathrm{AB}}{V} \propto [\ce{A}][\ce{B}]$$